# Setting a lifecycle for a path within a bucket

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto

Using Boto, you can create an S3 bucket and configure a lifecycle for it; say expire keys after 5 days. I would like to not have a default lifecycle for my bucket, but instead set a lifecycle depending on the path within the bucket. For instance, having path /a/ keys expire in 5 days, and path /b/ keys to never expire.

Is there a way to do this using Boto? Or is expiration tied to buckets and there is no alternative?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research in the boto docs, it looks like using the prefix parameter in the lifecycle add_rule method allows you to do this.